# Inconsistent display of unicode characters on web pages

Tags: asp.net, c, unicode

I have a C program that outputs some data including unicode non-English characters. It works fine in a Windows 7 command window, a Linux telnet session but used to fill a Label field on a ASP/html page it doesn't work in all situations - the platform that the web server is running on seems to affect the output.

Where I have a machine running Windows XP SP3 the program works fine in a command window but in the web page the characters are wrong. e.g. Ø is displayed as Ï.

The web page works fine where the web server is on Windows 7 and Server 2003 SP2. Web browser choice makes no difference.

Comment: Do you specify the character encoding in the HTML page?

Comment: You should include code that can be used to reproduce the problem, or a demo HTML document and its HTTP headers, and possibly a URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably one of [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).

The character encoding can be specified in each page or by setting a default value in the web server.

The Windows XP IIS probably has ISO-8859-1 as the default character set. 
you can either change it by configuring IIS or by specifying the character set in each HTML page.

Comment: Thanks Klas. The only place I could find encoding settings was in ASP.Net/Application/Globalization which is the same for the XP and Windows Server 2003 boxes. The web.config file is also the same.

Answer (score 1):

When Ø (U+00D8) is displayed as Ï (U+00CF), the probable explanation is that the HTML page is ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 encoded but the browser is interpreting it as CP 850 encoded. Check this using View → Encoding in your browser (it will show you the current encoding being applied to interpret the page, and you can change that to Windows-1252, which exists under some name (like “Western European (Windows)”) there. – There are some other [encodings](http://www.eki.ee/letter/chardata.cgi?ucode=00cf) in which the byte 0xD8 is interpreted as Ï.

If this turns out to be the right explanation, and even if not, check the *actual* and *declared* character encoding of the page and make sure that they match. See the W3C page
[Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).

Comment: Thanks Jukka. Not sure that's right as I can use the same browser to talk to two different web servers using the same server code + web pages and get two different results. So looks more likely the IIS settings. But they look the same on the XP and Server 2003 boxes :(. Anyway, the encoding according to Firefox is UTF-8 for both.

Comment: Hmmm, If I set the encoding to ISO-8859-1 or  Windows-1252 I get Ã.

Comment: Please note my request for clarification sent as comment to the original question. Guessing is fun, but you would get solid answers much faster if you posted sufficient data. If different browsers display the page differently this way, then most probably the page is not declaring the character encoding properly, and this is the problem to be addressed first.

Comment: Thanks Jukka, As I'm only maintaining the code determining what's relevant is a bit tricky. Most pages seem to have a resx file which has encoding="utf-8" at the top. The page in trouble doesn't have a resx so maybe I'll create an empty file and see what happens. Thanks for your patience.